# Java:How to load all files from a directory in ArrayList in Chunk and Process it

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an application where i need to load all files from a directory and upload into S3 .
The no of files in a directory is approx 100 millions small xmls files with size 15 GB .

This is how i am uploading it currently and process it .
But when files are less it works fine but when files are more grown up i get Out of memory error also and it does not work .

```
public class FileProcessThreads {

    private static Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(FileProcessThreads.class);

    public  ArrayList process(String fileLocation)  {

        _logger.info("Calling process method of FileProcessThreads class");
        File dir = new File(fileLocation);
        File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();
        ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
        if (directoryListing.length > 0) {

            for (File path : directoryListing) {
                String fileType =  FilenameUtils.getExtension (path.getName());
                long fileSize = path.length();
                if (fileType.equals("gz") && fileSize>0){
                    files.add(path);
                }

            }
        }
        _logger.info("Exiting  process method of FileProcessThreads class");
        return files;
    }
```

I think loading files in chuck might work .
But how can i do it ?
Also the files in directory keeps on coming in the same dir .

Can we increase the size of the array ?

Also i call this class in here

```
public class UploadExecutor {
    private static Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(UploadExecutor.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        _logger.info("----------STARTING JAVA MAIN METHOD----------------- ");

        /*
         * 3 C:\\Users\\u6034690\\Desktop\\TWOFILE\\xml
         * a205381-tr-fr-production-us-east-1-trf-auditabilty
         */
        while (true) {

            String strNoOfThreads = args[0];
            String strFileLocation = args[1];
            String strBucketName = args[2];

            int iNoOfThreads = Integer.parseInt(strNoOfThreads);
            S3ClientManager s3ClientObj = new S3ClientManager();
            AmazonS3Client s3Client = s3ClientObj.buildS3Client();


            try {

                FileProcessThreads fp = new FileProcessThreads();
                List<File> records = fp.process(strFileLocation);
                try {

                    _logger.info("No records found will wait for 10 Seconds");
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
                    records = fp.process(strFileLocation);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    _logger.error("InterruptedException: " + e.toString());
                }
                _logger.info("Total no of Audit files = " + records.size());

                if (records.size() >= 0) {
                    BuildThread BuildThreadObj = new BuildThread();
                    BuildThreadObj.buildThreadLogic(iNoOfThreads, s3Client, records, strFileLocation, strBucketName);
                }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                _logger.error("InterruptedException: " + t.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated .

I can not use below code  because i need to upload it into S3 as list of files .

```
Iterator<File> it = FileUtils.iterateFiles(folder, null, true);
  while (it.hasNext())
  {
     File fileEntry = (File) it.next();
  }
```

Comment: What line of code caused your out of memory? ` files.add(path);` isn't it?

Comment: @LuongDinh Yes ..But how can i chuck it

Comment: try like this 'List<File> files = new LinkedList<File>();' Then change your method return List intead of ArrayList.

Comment: @LuongDinh and i have to return List ? But can you please help me understand why LinkedList will work ? Also i am using MultiThreading in my application

Comment: LinkedList's effective for large of number items. They organize List by using pointer object intead of native array as ArrayList.

Comment: @LuongDinh let me try this .i will update you soon on this

Comment: I think 100 million not very big. But it's also good practice to load file by chunk as your resh of the idea. Then you can using FilterFile to implement it.

Comment: **Warning:** With `catch (Throwable t) { _logger.error("InterruptedException: " + t.toString()); }` you're possible lying about the cause of the throwable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return `File[]` from process method instead of `ArrayList`. And then in you main class, iterate over the files and upload in batches.

```
   public class FileProcessThreads {

        private static Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(FileProcessThreads.class);

        public  File[] getFiles(String fileLocation)  {

            _logger.info("Calling process method of FileProcessThreads class");
            File dir = new File(fileLocation);
            File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();
            ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
            if (directoryListing.length > 0)
                return directoryListing;
            _logger.info("Exiting  process method of FileProcessThreads class");
           return null;

        }
    }   

public class UploadExecutor {
    private static Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(UploadExecutor.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        _logger.info("----------STARTING JAVA MAIN METHOD----------------- ");

        /*
         * 3 C:\\Users\\u6034690\\Desktop\\TWOFILE\\xml
         * a205381-tr-fr-production-us-east-1-trf-auditabilty
         */
        while (true) {

            String strNoOfThreads = args[0];
            String strFileLocation = args[1];
            String strBucketName = args[2];

            int iNoOfThreads = Integer.parseInt(strNoOfThreads);
            S3ClientManager s3ClientObj = new S3ClientManager();
            AmazonS3Client s3Client = s3ClientObj.buildS3Client();


            try {

                FileProcessThreads fp = new FileProcessThreads();
                File[] files = fp.getFiles(strFileLocation);
                try {

                    _logger.info("No records found will wait for 10 Seconds");
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
                    files = fp.getFiles(strFileLocation);
                    ArrayList<File> batchFiles = new ArrayList<File>(batchSize);
                    if(null!=files){
                        for (File path : files) {
                            String fileType =  FilenameUtils.getExtension (path.getName());
                            long fileSize = path.length();
                            if (fileType.equals("gz") && fileSize>0){
                                batchFiles.add(path);
                            }
                            //wait till list size equals to batchSize
                            if (batchFiles.size() == batchSize) {
                                //upload batch to S3
                                BuildThread BuildThreadObj = new BuildThread();
                                BuildThreadObj.buildThreadLogic(iNoOfThreads, s3Client, batchFiles, strFileLocation, strBucketName);
                                batchFiles.clear();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //to consider remaining or files with count<batch size
                    if (! batch.isEmpty()) {
                        BuildThread BuildThreadObj = new BuildThread();
                        BuildThreadObj.buildThreadLogic(iNoOfThreads, s3Client, batchFiles, strFileLocation, strBucketName);
                        batchFiles.clear();
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    _logger.error("InterruptedException: " + e.toString());
                }
                _logger.info("Total no of Audit files = " + records.size());

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                _logger.error("InterruptedException: " + t.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for answer ...But i not calling UploadS3(files) method in this class .This class is getting called main class ..I have updated that code as well .So in this case i have pass Batch as parameter and clear out this in main class ? And also sometime the no of files will not be that much even sometime it will be like 10 files only

Comment: **Warning:** You're using a raw type (`ArrayList`).

Comment: @MCEmperor Thanks for pointing it out. We should never use raw type

Comment: I got this error when i tried with batch size 100000`

2019-04-27 17:37:37 INFO  - Number of record to be uploaded  in current thread: : 5000
2019-04-27 17:41:33 ERROR - AmazonClientException Unable to calculate MD5 hash: D:\TRFAudits1\201839_116731_ANA_12AC33BD-400C-44FB-88A0-37868C3D1047.xml.gz (Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service)


It threw this error`

Comment: @Anupam people are not here to fix your issues but to help you fix your issues

Answer (score 0):

With Java Streams and functional interface you can do:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FileStream {

    public static void process(String fileLocation,String extension, Consumer<List<File>> handler, int chunkSize)
    {
        ArrayList<File> chunk = new ArrayList<File>();

        Stream.of(new File(fileLocation).listFiles((path, filename) ->  filename.endsWith(extension)))
        .forEach((f)->{
            chunk.add(f);
            if(chunk.size()>=chunkSize)
            {
                handler.accept(chunk);
                chunk.clear();
            }
        });
        // process remaining files
        handler.accept(chunk);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Consumer<List<File>> handler =new Consumer<List<File>> () {

            @Override
            public void accept(List<File> fileList) {
                System.out.println("new file list "+fileList);
                // Upload to S3
            }
        };
        FileStream.process("d:\\downloads",".gz", handler, 1000);
    }
}
```

Each time the `chunk` list reaches the chunkSize, the handler is called to process the list.
I've added a main() jsut to show how `process()` should be called.

Worth noting: The method `java.io.File.listFiles()` also exists with FileFilter or FilenameFilter to reduce already the list of files.